# por que el maestro detalle falla ruby on rails

Tags: bootstrap, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Es un maestro de detalle el padre reuniones el hijo es detalles_reuniones, detalles_reuniones, detalles_reuniones tiene asociacion con producto.
en este formulario hay autocomplete y select.

es  un formulario aninados  no  funciona es para agregar mas productos.

Le doy clic en el carrito  y no vuelve a  traer el  otro carrito y  me recarga la pagina.

**ReunionesController**

```
class ReunionesController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_reunion, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

 autocomplete  :centro_costo, :fullname, :full => true, :column_name => 'fullname'

# GET /reuniones
# GET /reuniones.json
def index
  @reuniones = Reunion.all
  @negocios = Negocio.all
end
def select_region
  rs = Region.where(:negocio_id => params[:idnegocio]).order('nombre').all
  respond_to do |format|
  format.json {render json: rs }
    puts "funciono "
  format.html
  end
end

def select_ciudad
  rs = Ciudad.where(:region_id => params[:idregion]).order('nombre').all
  respond_to do |format|
  format.json {render json: rs }
  format.html
  end
end

def select_planta
  rs = Planta.where(:ciudad_id => params[:idciudad]).order('nombre').all
  respond_to do |format|
  format.json {render json: rs }
  format.html
  end
end


# GET /reuniones/1
# GET /reuniones/1.json
def show
end

  # GET /reuniones/new
  def new
    Time.zone = 'America/Bogota' 
    @reunion = Reunion.new(fecha_entrega: Time.zone.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
    @reunion.detalles_reuniones.build
    @negocios = Negocio.all 
  end

  # GET /reuniones/1/edit
  def edit
    @negocios = Negocio.all
   end

# POST /reuniones
# POST /reuniones.json
def create

 centro_costo = CentroCosto.find_by(fullname: reunion_params[:centro_costo_fullname])
 @reunion = Reunion.new(reunion_params)
 @reunion.centro_costo_id = centro_costo.try(:id)
  respond_to do |format|
      if @reunion.save
      format.html { redirect_to @reunion, notice: 'La reunión se creó correctamente.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @reunion }
    else
    @negocios = Negocio.all
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @reunion.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
 end

  # PATCH/PUT /reuniones/1
  # PATCH/PUT /reuniones/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @reunion.update(reunion_params)
         format.html { redirect_to @reunion, notice: 'La reunión se actualizó correctamente.' }
         format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @reunion }
      else
        @negocios = Negocio.all
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @reunion.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

 # DELETE /reuniones/1
 # DELETE /reuniones/1.json
def destroy
   @reunion.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to reuniones_url, notice: 'Reunión fue destruida con éxito.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end

private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_reunion
    @reunion = Reunion.find(params[:id])
  end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def reunion_params
  params.require(:reunion).permit(:hora_pedido, :fecha_pedido,:hora_inicio, :hora_final, :fecha_entrega, :observacion, :subtotal,
  :planta_id, :ubicacion,:centro_costo_fullname,:hora_entre,:nombre,
  detalles_reuniones_attributes: [:id, :reunion_id, :cantidad, :valor, :producto_id, :_destroy])
end
end
```

**modelo reunion**

```
class Reunion < ApplicationRecord

 belongs_to :planta
 belongs_to :centro_costo

 #maestro de detalle
 has_many :detalles_reuniones, :dependent => :destroy
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :detalles_reuniones, allow_destroy: true

 def detalles_reuniones_for_form
     collection = detalles_reuniones.where(reunion_id: id)
     collection.any? ? collection : detalles_reuniones.build
 end



 #Autocomplete
  def centro_costo_fullname
    centro_costo.fullname if centro_costo
  end

  def centro_costo_fullname=(fullname)
   self.centro_costo = CentroCosto.find_by_fullname(fullname) unless fullname.blank?
  end

end
```

**_form**

```
  <%= simple_form_for(@reunion) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <div class="form-inputs">  
    <div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-md-4"></div>
    <div class ="col-xs-12  col-sm-6 col-md-4">

        <%= f.input   :nombre,label: "Nombre de reunion",
         placeholder: "Ingrese el nombre de  la reunion",input_html: { title: 'Nombre de la reunion' }%> 

    </div
    <div class = "col-md-4"></div>
    </div>

  <div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-md-2"></div>
    <div class = "col-xs-12  col-sm-6 col-md-2">


        <center><%= f.label :Hora_de_entrega %></center>
          <center><%= f.input :hora_entre,:label => false ,input_html: { title: 'Hora de entrega de los refrigerios' } %></center>
     </div>

    <div class ="col-xs-6  col-sm-6 col-md-2">
      <center><%= f.label :hora_inicio %></center>
      <center><%= f.input :hora_inicio,:label => false ,input_html: { title: 'Hora de inicio de la reunion' } %></center>

    </div>

    <div class = "col-xs-6  col-sm-6 col-md-2">

      <%= f.input :hora_final,input_html: { title: 'Hora en la que termina  la reunion ' } %>
    </div>

    <div class = "col-xs-12  col-sm-6 col-md-2">
      <%= f.input :fecha_entrega, as: :datetime_picker,
        input_html: {value:reunion.fecha_entrega.try(:strftime, '%d/%m/%Y'),
          data: {date_options: {format: 'DD/MM/YYYY', ignoreReadonly: true}}} 
          %>
    </div>
    <div class = "col-md-2"></div>
  </div>




     <div class = "row">
   <div class = "col-md-2"></div>
    <div class ="col-xs-12  col-sm-4 col-md-3">
      <label>Negocio</label>
      <%= select_tag "negocio", options_from_collection_for_select(@negocios, "id", "nombre"),
      class: "form-control", :include_blank => "Seleccione Pais"  %>
    </div>  

    <div class ="col-xs-12  col-sm-4 col-md-3">
      <label>region</label>
      <%= select_tag "region", "<option value="">Seleccione region</option>".html_safe, 
      class: "form-control" %>
    </div>

     <div class ="col-xs-12  col-sm-4 col-md-2">
     <label>ciudad</label>
     <%= select_tag "ciudad", "<option value="">Seleccione una ciudad</option>".html_safe,
      class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
    <div class = "col-md-2"></div>
</div>


  <div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-md-2"></div>
    <div class ="col-xs-12  col-sm-4 col-md-2">
        <label>Planta</label>
       <%= select_tag "reunion[planta_id]","<option value="">Seleccione una planta</option>".html_safe,
       class: "form-control" %>

    </div>
    <div class = "col-xs-12  col-sm-4 col-md-3">
      <%= f.input :ubicacion , placeholder: "Ingrese la ubicacion del salon",
      input_html: { title: 'La ubicacion donde se va llevar los refrigerios' }%>
    </div>
    <div class = "col-xs-12  col-sm-4 col-md-3">
     <%= f.input :centro_costo_fullname,label: "Centro de costo", :url => autocomplete_centro_costo_fullname_reuniones_path,
      :as => :autocomplete,input_html: { title: 'Centro de costos' } %>
    </div>
    <div class = "col-md-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>  
  </div> 
  <div class="row">
    <div class=" col-sm-1 col-xs-1 col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-10  col-sm-10  col-md-8 ">
     <hr>
      <div class="row compact wello">
       <%= f.fields_for :detalles_reuniones do |detalles_reuniones_for_form| %>
       <%= render 'detalle_reunion_fields',  f: detalles_reuniones_for_form %>
       <% end %>
       <%= link_to_add_fields '<i class="fa fa-cart-arrow-down fa-3x color-red"  
     aria-hidden="true"></i>'.html_safe,  f, :detalles_reuniones %>
     </div>
     <hr> 
   </div>
 <div class="col-md-2  col-sm-1 col-xs-1"></div>
 </div>



<div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-md-3"></div>
    <div class ="col-xs-12  col-sm-4 col-md-3">

      <%= f.input   :observacion ,label: "Campo de observacion",
      as: :text, :input_html => { :style=> '  resize: none; ',
      :size =>"5x5", :maxlength => 300 ,title: 'Observaciones '},
      placeholder: "Ingrese por que incumple con las politica del negocio. " %> 


    </div>
    <div class = "col-md-3">
      <%= f.input :subtotal,input_html: { title: 'Sudtotal de refrigerios' } %>
    </div>
    <div class = "col-md-3"></div>
    </div> 


 <div class="form-actions">
   <%= f.button :submit %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

**HELPER REUNION**

```
 module ReunionesHelper

 def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
    new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
    id = new_object.object_id
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |detalles_reuniones_for_form|
        render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", f: detalles_reuniones_for_form)
    end
     link_to(name, '', class: "add_fields", data: { id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n", "")})
 end    

end
```

**reuniones.coffee**

```
jQuery ->
$(document).on 'click', '.remove_fields', (event) ->
  $(this).prev('input[type=hidden]').val('1')
  $(this).closest('fieldset').hide()
  event.preventDefault()

$(document).on 'click', '.add_fields', (event) ->
  time = new Date().getTime()
  regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
  $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))
  event.preventDefault()
```

**MODELO DETALLE_REUNION**

```
class DetalleReunion < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :reunion, optional: true

  self.table_name = 'detalles_reuniones' 

  belongs_to :producto

 end
```

**Log**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando doy clic en el carrito vuelve y carga de  la pagina.

Hola mire  hize un ejemplo lo que deberia hacer, las fotos esta en este vinculo https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B8tEXZ0-P1YHSkE1TFRid0ZhWjA?usp=sharing
gracias

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con maestro? Y agrega el log del server y también de la consola de desarrollo del browser si es que es relevante, porque `Le doy clic en agregar otro maestro me recarga la pagina, y no me deja hacer mas maestros` en realidad no dice mucho de lo que te está sucediendo.

Comment: @AlterLagos ya la actualice es cuando uno puede agregar muchos productos de en un mismo formulario. gracia.

Comment: Aún falta que agregues el log para ver qué está ocasionando el problema.

Comment: @Gerry ,ya esta  actualizada, gracias  estaba enfermo.

Comment: @AlterLagos ya esta actualizada, gracias estaba enfermo

Comment: ¿Cuál es el comportamiento que debería tener?

Comment: @Gerry, estos es un  ejemplo  que encontré en Internet, detalle venta cada vez  se agrega un producto  o una descripción, esto lo que quiero hacer  agregar mas productos.   NO ES MISMO  CODIGO DE LA PAGINA, GRACIAS, http://blog.gmartinez.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/06.jpg  ,

Comment: hola alguien ha encontrado el error?

Comment: Miguel, miré el link que agregaste, pero sigo sin tener claro el error. ¿Podrías describir un ejemplo de lo que debería hacer la aplicación?, ¿qué debería pasar al dar clic en el carrito?

Comment: @Gerry ya esta actualizada , gracias

Answer (score 0):

El error<sup>1</sup> está en el *script* dentro de *reuniones.coffee*, debes ejecutar `event.preventDefault()` antes del resto del código para que este tenga el efecto deseado.

Actualiza tu archivo *reuniones.coffee* así:

```
jQuery ->
$(document).on 'click', '.remove_fields', (event) ->
  event.preventDefault()
  $(this).prev('input[type=hidden]').val('1')
  $(this).closest('fieldset').hide()

$(document).on 'click', '.add_fields', (event) ->
  event.preventDefault()
  time = new Date().getTime()
  regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
  $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))
```

<sup>1</sup> *Al tener `event.preventDefault()` al final, este no evita que el enlace al que se da clic (e.g. aquel con la clase `.remove_fields`) cargue la URL que tenga de referencia (en el atributo `href`); en este caso, debido a que el enlace generado con `link_to_add_fields` apunta a la misma página donde está (i.e. `new.html.erb`),se recarga la misma página al dar clic en el.*

Comment: no  toda habia recarga la pagina.@Gerry, gracias

Comment: @MIGUELANGELGILRODRIGUEZ ¿Qué te muestra la consola del navegador?